# Can I wrap my whole HTTP request in a single transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I've got a PHP app with a custom model layer built on top of PDO.  Each of my models is a separate class (with a common base class) that manages interactions with a given table (all SELECTs, INSERTs, and UPDATEs for the given table are instance methods of the given class).  However, all the classes share a single PDO object, with a single DB connection, which is passed into the constructor of the model class, in a very simplistic form of dependency injection.

This is a bit of a simplification, but it works something like this:

```
<?php
    $pdo = new \PDO(/*connection details*/);
    $modelA = new ModelA($pdo);
    $modelB = new ModelB($pdo);
    $thingA = $modelA->find(1234); //where 1234 is the primary key
    $thingB = $modelB->create([
        'modelb_id' => $thingA->id,
        'notes' => 'This call generates an runs an insert statement based on the array of fields and values passed in, applying specialized business logic, and other fun stuff.'
    ]);
    print_r($thingB); // Create returns an object containing the data from the newly created row, so this would dump it to the screen.
```

At any rate, currently, everything just runs through PDO's prepared statements and gets committed immediately, because we're not using transactions.  For the most part that's fine, but we're running into some issues.

First, if the database interaction is more complicated than what you see above, you can have a request that generates a large number of SQL queries, including several INSERTs and UPDATEs, that are all interrelated.  If you hit an error or exception midway through the execution, the first half of the database stuff is already committed to the database, but everything after that never runs.  So you get orphaned records, and other bad data.  I know that is essentially the exact problem transaction were invented to solve, so it seems like a compelling case to use them.

The other thing we're running into is intermittent MySQL deadlocks when running at high traffic volumes.  I'm still trying to get to the bottom of these, but I suspect transactions would help here, too, from what I'm reading.

Here's the thing though.  My database logic is abstracted (as it should be), which ends up scattering it a bit.  What I'm thinking I'd like to do is create a transaction right when I create my PDO object, and then all the queries run with the PDO object would be part of that transaction.  Then as part of my app's tear down sequence for an HTTP request, commit the transaction, after everything has been done.  And in my error handling logic, I'd probably want to call rollback.

I'm going to do some experimentation before I try to implement this fully, but I was hoping to get some feedback from someone who might have gone down with road, about whether I'm on the right track, or this is actually a terrible idea, or some tips for a more successful implementation.  I also have some specific questions concerns:

Will wrapping everything in transactions cause a performance hit?  It seems like if you've got multiple simultaneous transactions, they have to be queued, so the first transaction can complete before the second can run.  Or else you'd have to cache the state for your database, so that all the events in one transaction can follow their logical progression?  Maybe not.  Maybe it's actually faster.  I have no idea.

We use MySQL replication.  One environment uses MySQL's Master-Slave support, with the bin log format set to STATEMENT.  The other environment uses Percona Cluster, with Master-Master replication.  Are there any replication implications of this model?

Is there a timeout for the transaction?  And when it times out, does it commit or rollback?  I expect my normal application logic will either commit or rollback, depending on whether there was an error.  But if the whole thing crashes, what happens to the transaction I've been building?

I mentioned we're running into MySQL deadlocks.  I've added some logic to my models, where when PDO throws a PDOException, if it's a 1213, I catch it, sleep for up to 3 seconds, then try again.  What happens to my transaction if there's a deadlock, or any PDOException for that matter?  Does it automatically rollback?  Or does it leave it alone, so I can attempt to recover?

What other risks am I completely overlooking that I need to account for?  I can try out my idea and do some tests, but I'm worried about the case where everything I know to look for works, but what about the things I don't know to look for that come up when I push it out into the wild?

Right now, I don't use a connection pooling, I just create a connection for each request, shared between all the model classes.  But if I want to do connection pooling later, how does that interact with transactions?

I have a pretty clear picture of how and where to start the transaction, with when I create my shared PDO object.  But is there a best practice for the commit part?  I have a script that does other teardown stuff for each request.  I could put it there.  I could maybe subclass PDO, and add it to the destructor, but I've never done much with constructors in PHP.

Oh yeah, I need to get clear about how nested transactions work.  In my preliminary tests, it looks like you can call BEGIN several times, and the first time you call COMMIT, it commits everything back to the first BEGIN.  And any subsequent COMMITs don't do much.  Is that right, or did I misinterpret my tests?

Comment: Transactions don't *necessarily* lock or run in the order they're executed. It really depends if there's any inter-dependencies. Generally you should only isolate *exactly* what you need to be atomic inside a transaction as getting too carried away here leads to deadlocks.

Comment: Long running transactions should always be avoided, particularly with repeatable read isolation. Don't start the transaction until you are ready to write and try to do as little logic in the transaction as possible. Also, auto retries can lead to thundering herd syndrome. Innodb_lock_wait_timeout is a configurable option.

Comment: Thanks @tadman.  I certainly don't want to make MORE deadlocks.  I'd also thought about just using a transaction to wrap my code in the edit() and create() methods.  But sometimes one model's create() method calls another, so you'd have nested transactions, and I'm concerned about unintended side effects there.

Comment: @winmutt, My automatic retries are limited to 5 attempts, but I agree this is something to be careful about.

Comment: You really have to be ready to rock and roll when you crack open a transaction. Taking your time inside of one can hold up everyone else trying to commit and in a worst-case scenario can cause a total melt-down as one slow transaction slows down another. You'll need to balance the desire for an atomic commit with the practicality of holding open a transaction for too long.

Comment: That makes sense.  Do big ORMs like Doctrine, PHPActiveRecord, Eloquent, etc. use transactions for their writes by default?  I seem to recall Doctrine would let you create and commit transactions, but I never cracked it open to look inside and see whether it used them internally.

Comment: "I have some minor table locking issues that I would like to turn into *major* table locking issues via long-running transactions."

Comment: @Sammitch, so you're saying it's a bad idea? ;)  Fair enough.  My understanding, right or wrong, was that using transactions might avoid deadlocks, in the case where you have two update processes with multiple interrelated queries, because it would force one transaction to go through first, avoiding deadlocks arising from running the two sets of queries simultaneously.

I freely admit, I don't know what I'm talking about here.  Can you suggest a better approach?  I'm here to learn.

Comment: @eimajenthat if a query is going to cause a lock then a transaction isn't going to change that, it may even extend the duration of the lock. If a query *isn't* going to cause a lock a transaction might make it lock anyway. Transactions should *only* be used in the case that multiple tables *must* be updated *in-sync* to preserve data integrity. That said, you should consider your choice of table types as MyISAM only has table-level locking whereas InnoDB has row-level locking. Honestly, unless you're looking for fulltext or spatial indexing you should *always* use InnoDB, IMHO.

Comment: @Sammitch, oh yeah, I'm only using InnoDB.  Latest version of InnoDB has fulltext search as well; excited about that.  Based on all the comments here, the only place I'm still thinking about using transactions is where I have a method in my models that generates several INSERTs and UPDATEs, because if it fails part way through, I'd like to be able to roll it back.  Even there I'm wondering if it wouldn't do more harm than good.  At this point I'm looking for ways to reduce my deadlocks, and putting the transaction question on the back burner.

Comment: @eimajenthat the more you say the more it sounds like this is all happening as it should and you're not likely to be able to avoid the locking issues. In this case you can either invest in more horsepower for MySQL so these queries move faster, or look into stuffing these operations into a queue and processing them outside of the scope of an HTTP request.